# what is the new version of styleabletoast

Tags: android, android-manifest

Manifest merger failed :

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.1.2] C:\Users\java\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\styleabletoast-2.1.2.aar\9c4fc146927a85bf2fdc6fca1c3fb32a\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.muddzdev.styleabletoastlibrary" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Comment: you have answer in your log

Answer (score 0):

> **Suggestion:** use a compatible library *with a minSdk of at most 15*

It's pretty clear what you should do.

Library supports `minsdk >= 16` only so, change your minsdk to upper than 16 or equal.

---

Also, if you're looking for new version of a library, search the library name and version like this: `com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.1.2` then you'll see results which includes library's github page and maybe more. So, they should be providing the latest versions on their github page but if you still couldn't see it, look for where the author of library uploaded. for e.x: maven, jcenter or whatever then you'll be able to see the latest version on the library's page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all available versions here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.muddzdev/styleabletoast